# Java String.split with "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" still showing whitespace as a word

Tags: java, regex, string, inverted-index

I am having a problem with a program that creates a word to frequency map for a given document in Java. When I print all the words out I still see " " as a 'word'.

Here is the paraphrased code:

```
String delimiters = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+";
String[] words;
SortedSet<String> allWords = new TreeSet<String>();
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    words = line.split(delimiters);
    for all words add the word to the allWords set and the wordMap
}

for (String word : allWords) {
    System.out.println(word + " : " + wordMap.get(word).entrySet());
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Time elapsed: 0.75 seconds.
 : [books/dickens.txt=7]       // WHAT ARE YOU?!?! How does this happen??!?!
10 : [books/dickens.txt=2]
11th : [books/dickens.txt=2]
12th : [books/dickens.txt=2]
```

How is this whitespace showing up?
Thanks

ps if you want to see the full code here is [a link](https://github.com/tdoshea90/cs1501WordFrequencyVector/blob/master/src/ComputeDistanceBetween.java)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis everything but lower and upper case letters and numbers?? ^ means not.

Comment: It's not a space, it's the empty string.  After `for (int k = 0; k < words.length; k++) {` just put `if (words[k].length == 0) continue;`

Comment: Everyone marking Sotirios' comment as helpful lacks an understanding of regular expressions.

Comment: @SeanBright I think they misread the question and assumed it was asking why `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` was matching whitespace.  But either way, it's not a helpful comment, since the use of `^` wasn't actually the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a white space is an empty string.
This happens when you have empty lines inside the file.

doing something like this

```
words = "".split(delimiters);
```

results in an array having one element and that element is an empty string.

Comment: so I should check if line == " " first??

Comment: No, you should check if each word in `words` is empty before doing anything with it.  `String.split()` will return an array that could have the empty string as 1 or more elements (if you have two characters in a row that match your `delimiters`)

Comment: you could do that, or, after you processed all the lines just remove the empty string key from your maps.

Comment: Lines that are only-spaces (or only-'delimeters') will also have an `""` empty-string match. It would be more efficient to just add a check for "" inside the loop which you describe as 'for all words add the word to the allWords set and the wordMap'. Also, not you should do `\word.length() == 0` or `"".equals(word)`, and not `"" == word`

Comment: @SeanBright - he will not get "" between delimiters because of the '+' at the end of the split match regex.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone, just so I understand how this is working instead of mindlessly copy pasting code, whenever multiple delimiters occur, like ?!, ?! will be replaced with the empty string "", correct? If so then that means I need to check for the empty string after the string is split.

Comment: @rolfl - `" one ".split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");` returns two elements.  One of them is the empty string.

Comment: @Tim - No.  As rolfl pointed out, you are using `+` which gobbles up multiple delimiters.  The issue occurs when you have a delimiter character at the beginning of a line.  Your solution is correct, check to make sure that `words[k]` isn't empty before you put it in your map.

Comment: @rolfl - You're right though, I misspoke in my original comment.